# Magento redirects from virtualhost to localhost

Tags: magento2.2.2

In hosts:

`127.0.0.1 www.demomage.com`

In httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName demomage
ServerAlias www.demomage.com
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/mage
<Directory  "/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But on www.demomage.com Magento redirects to localhost/mage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just needed to add changes to core_config_data (web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url fields)